# Starting external process from within java application - memory consideration

Tags: java, jvm

Long time ago there was an issue (I believe affecting only Java on *nix operating systems) with spawning external processes from Java due to the fact that JVM / OS was allocating same amount of memory for new process as available to JVM.

So if you have "big" Java application which starts relatively small process, you may run into memory problems because process cannot be started due to insufficient amount of memory available to create this new process.

I'm trying to confirm whether this issue has been resolved in recent versions of Java 7/8.

I found this bug report which is marked as resolved: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=5049299 - can anyone confirm if indeed this problem has been addressed and starting external processes from within JVM is considered now as "safe"?

Comment: In the EVALUATION section, it is said that only Solaris was ever affected by this, Linux is mentioned as unaffected explicitly.

Comment: There are some pages on the internet that suggest that Linux is also affected (at least some releases): https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/forking-jvm-error-12-cannot-allocate-memory-or-error-12-not-enough-space-779171744.html so I wanted to make sure...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is resolved in 7u60 and 8. 
The affected version of the bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5049299) confirms that linux, solaris9 and solaris10.

But from bug it is not clear that starting external processes from within JVM is considered now as "safe"? 
One of the evaluation from Mark suggest

"Within the constraints of the existing semantics of Runtime.exec there does
not appear to be any way to avoid this in current Solaris releases. vfork(2)
is not thread-safe and popen(3C) only provides access to one of the child's
standard streams rather than all three of them. S10 does support the new
posix_spawn call; we should look into using that when running on S10"